# Question about an application of Poincare-Bendixon Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question seeks to ask the reader to show that the differential equation $\frac{d^2z}{dt^2} + \left(z^2 + \left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^4 - 2\right)z = 0$ has some non-trivial periodic solution.

I started by setting up the system $$\frac{dx}{dt} = y$$$$\frac{dy}{dt} = x^3 - xy^4 + 2x.$$

I (and other classmates) tried to do the problem as follows: We took $$\frac{d}{dt}(x^2 + y^2)$$ and we get some equation, but we can't seem to put it in forms of that equation (essentially a distance function). We also have trouble finding the correct region to apply Poincare-Bendixon.

I'm not sure if the question as stated is incorrect or if I need a different approach to this problem.

Comment: $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is a saddle point for the second system, thus a bad candidate for the center of a limit cycle. You have some sign differences between the two formulations of the equation. With the signs of the first equation, $(x,y)=(0,0)$ appears to be a true center in the stream plot, indicating the possibility of the existence of a first integral.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the system

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = y\\
\frac{dy}{dt} = -x^3 - xy^4 + 2x
$$

we have at $(0,0)$ a saddle and at $(\pm\sqrt 2, 0)$ two centers.

The stream plot is represented by

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: @LutzL Yes. You have reason. Follows the correct stream plot. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that one. Now if one could find a first integral so that the closed orbits follow from the level curves,...

Comment: $y\dot y =-(x^2+y^4-2)x\dot x$ or making $X = x^2, Y = y^2$ then $\dot Y = -(X+Y^2-2)\dot X$ or  $Y' = -(X+Y^2-2)$

Comment: Which is a Riccati equation leading to solutions by Airy functions. Solving for the constants gives then a first integral $C=F(X,Y)=F(x^2,y^2)$ proving that the solutions follow indeed the level sets. Now proving the boundedness of some of those could be quite difficult.